# martingale, stopping times

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stopping-times

Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be stopping times,
prove that $(\sigma+\tau) \land T$ (T is the end-time point) is also a stopping time.
So I have already proved that $\sigma+\tau$ is a stopping time, if I can prove that $T$ is also a stopping time then I would be finished? But is the end time automatically a stopping time? or do I have to use another approach with a case distinction? (e.g. $(\sigma+\tau) >  T$ and $(\sigma+\tau) \leq  T$)

Comment: Have you shown that a constant is a stopping time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is immediate that
$$
\{T\leqslant t\}\in \mathcal F_t
$$
for all $t$. Now, since $\sigma+\tau$ and $T$ are stopping times, we have
$$
\{(\sigma+\tau)\wedge T\leqslant t\} = \{\sigma+\tau\leqslant t\}\cup \{T\leqslant t\}\in\mathcal F_t
$$
for all $t$, and hence $(\sigma+\tau)\wedge T$ is a stopping time.

Comment: thank you very much